# Are there any free phosphorus-31 NMR spectral libraries?

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, reference-request

I know that there are some sites like Sigma Aldrich and AIST for $\ce{^1H}$ NMR and $\ce{^13C}$ NMR, but was wondering if there were any free sites to compare $\ce{^31P}$ NMR spectra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few it seems, a couple of examples are below:

University of Wisconsin [Phosphorus NMR data](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/handouts/nmr/p-data.htm), starts with a shifts overview.

Stanford's Magnetic Resonance Laboratory site [P NMR at the SMRL](http://smrl.stanford.edu/pnmr/), provides comparisons and a protocol for testing.

A general NMR site is [NMR Wiki](http://nmrwiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Databases) - has many links to many sources.